# Disable flyway for Non springboot project - Normal maven -spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, flyway

I want to disable flyway for a certain environment but can't find a way to do it

Below are the version of stack

1. Spring - 3.2
2. Flyway - 4.0.3
3. Mysql - 5.6.3

Exploring flyway and open to any approach for disabling to

**Looked for a lot, but all I can find is how to disable it for spring-boot.**

Can anyone please help?

Also I want to use core spring this features through spring and maven, and not via java classes

Answer (score 0):

If you could update Spring to version 4 you could use the [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html)  with a custom [`Condition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) to create the Flyway bean conditionally.

Comment: It's really a big project and I don't think it can be migrated right now. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Also i want to use core spring this features through spring and maven, and not via java classes

Comment: @guarav9620 you mean XML config?